# Near impossible: change HP EliteBook 68SAD Ver. F.62 BIOS with Prema BIOS

Tags: bios, hp-elitebook

At first you are of course going to ask "Why would anyone want to do that?!" So my job now is to provide some context. I have a HP EliteBook 8760w with NVIDIA Quadro 3000M. The lacking performance of the latter always bothered me, so my ambition now is to upgrade to a far better GPU. My goal is to successfully swap my old 3000M with NVIDIA GeForce GTX 980M. I know that HP keeps a whitelist of specific "suitable" GPUs, so at first I thought this was a no-go. But then I found two very detailed and sophisticated threads which describe the workarounds (you can find them [here](http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/hp-elitebook-8770w-and-970m-6gb-and-980m-8gb-they-work.786791/) and [here](http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/8770w-compatible-video-cards.795753/)).

The first problem I run into is that I am **completely clueless about BIOS flashing/replacement**. All of the tutorials on YouTube are showing certain types of "primitive" BIOSes being replaced by Prema BIOS. But *my* BIOS is (as the title suggests) **68SAD Ver. F.62 BIOS**, and from the looks of it far more advanced. I am afraid of bricking my machine, so please, help me if you can! The fact that the thread user **artpra** mentions that 980M works with **Prema 1.1.1. vBIOS** (you can see this statement via the second link on first page, second post) only adds to the confusion.

I think that the most efficient way of helping me is to study the techniques used and documented by artpra (**and then "translate" them for my lowly understanding of the matter**). This way, you will know the context and my end-goal. Please don't immediately label this comment as off-topic, I just had a ton of explaining to do.

To wrap this up: **Do you know ANY WAY to change my current BIOS to Prema 1.1.1 vBIOS?** If so, please don't hesitate to answer. Thank you in advance!

Comment: @McDonald's Um, I actually haven't bought GTX 980M. My plan was to first see how the system responds (and recognises) this MXM GPU and then work from there. Sorry if I let you down, you are correct, it probably IS a very stupid idea to be asking that question before you even have the hardware needed. The end goal is the following: **GTX 980M must work on my device in its full compasity (for gaming; usually this is done via Prema BIOS Mod, as it supports ALL hardware that physically suits the system).**

Comment: @McDonald's Yes, I've seen both of the videos you linked. What scared me away is the message at 4:50 in the first linked video: "Please make sure that you have the right model of computer..." It basically tells me that if I do not have a Clevo, this mod will mess my laptop up. But is this really true? I'll leave that up to you to answer, I trust you. But yes, I was already planning to try the fix in the second video if something goes horribly wrong. Thank you anyway. :)

Comment: This is certainly a task too dangerous for my to confirm whether or not it will work but I'd go thru the process of seeing the restore BIOS screen comes up to confirm your model actually supports that functionality just in case it is needed for a potential backout solution. Maybe others can help you more as this is something that's dangerous and could hose up the system. If you're going to do it, at some point you'd just have to give it a try and keep your fingers crossed regardless of how much you read, plan, etc. I'm not a gamer so this is a hack I'd never personally attempt.

Comment: @McDonald's Yes, it IS risky, but hey, what is life if you don't risk sometimes? Tell you what: ket's take this nice and slow; Firstly, I'll buy my GTX 980M and put it in my system and observe the consequences. ONLY THEN if the functionality won't be satisfactory, I'll try to flash BIOS. I can't lose any data from my SSD, righ? I'll just brick my physical device. He he he... (nervous, but excited).

Comment: Yes, that should be correct, the SSD data should be retained for sure!! I look forward to hearing the outcome.

Comment: @GregorPerčič, **artpra** posted that she "personally tested all of them with **F.61 BIOS**". So they should work with your current bios as well.

Comment: @VaradMahashabde But I have F.62 BIOS...

Comment: @GregorPerčič the older versions are always available, just check if the newer version didn't have particularly significant update or bug fix before flashing.

Comment: Downgrade : Restore BIOS to a previous version, follow this HP document: http://support.hp.com/in-en/document/c02693833